# How to downgrade from Internet Explorer 11 to Internet Explorer 10?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

As a developer, I found the new Internet Explorer version to be a complete nightmare. I turned the windows feature off, but I wasn't able to install [Internet Explorer 10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_11#Internet_Explorer_10). It says that it's already installed which it is not. Is there a file or a [registry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry) entry I should delete as well?

Comment: Before uninstalling IE11 press F12 and look at Document Mode. Some enterprise group policies modify this. Click on it and choose Standards. See if the problem goes away. It seems servers in the intranet zone automatically are rendered in Compatibility mode.

Comment: As a developer I concur with the highest level of attrition.

Comment: Further to @DeveloperDan's comment: Document Mode in IE 11 is under the new Emulation tab (scroll down the icons on the left to the last one.)  It wasn't easy to find!

Comment: Firstly I misread it as "upgrade", but then considering it is IE, it all makes sense now.

Comment: @DeveloperDan my compatability mode doesn't even have emulation or document mode. Just a heads up for others who might be in same situation.

Comment: You might find this 'Toolkit to Disable Automatic Delivery of Internet Explorer 11' useful as well. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=40722. It is a script from Microsoft. You can just run `IE11_Blocker.cmd /B` from the command line after you extract it.

Answer (score 228, accepted):

1. Go to *Control Panel* -> *Programs* -> *Programs and features*

   [image: Step 1 - Programs and features]
2. Go to *Windows Features* and disable *Internet Explorer 11*

   [image: Step 2 - Windows Features]

   [image: Step 3 - Uncheck Internet Explorer 11]
3. Then click on *Display installed updates*

   [image: Step 4 - Display installed updates]
4. Search for *Internet explorer*
5. Right-click on *Internet Explorer 11* -> *Uninstall*

   [image: Step 5 - Uninstall Internet Explorer 11]
6. Do the same with Internet *Explorer 10*
7. Restart your computer
8. Install [Internet Explorer 10 here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/internet-explorer.aspx) (old broken [link](http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/E/0/CE0AB8AE-E6B7-43F7-9290-F8EB0EA54FB5/IE10-Windows6.1-x64-en-us.exe))

I think it will be okay.

Comment: Tried this. now, when I'm trying to install IE10 it says "more recent  version of IE is installed on your computer"

Comment: I don't know what you have tried before to uninstall IE11, but maybe you have done something wrong, so install again IE11 through Windows update. Then try what I have said (please do not forget to restart your computer once it is uninstalled).

Comment: Thanks kmas, You were almost there.
Now I managed to solve this. You need to uninstall IE11 from 3 places:
1. windows features
2. Installed updates - Uninstall Internet Explorer 11
2. Installed updates - Uninstall Windows Internet Explorer 10.
Update your answer and I'll mark it as a solution

Comment: I didn't know you had to disable IE in Windows Features to install again IE. Thanks for the tip. ;)

Comment: Came to this page twice already, first time it worked on my laptop. Second time I had to [properly install java](http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp) on my desktop.

Comment: Didn't work for me - I think there might be some kind of policy preventing the uninstall of IE on my corporate machine.

Comment: The java install is required to detect different bit versions properly so you can execute step 4. Example: you want to downgrade IE11 64bit to IE10 64bit but the previously installed IE10 is a 32bit version => install Java 32bit and 64bit.

Comment: Has anyone be able to get this to work on Windows 8.1?

Comment: Win7 64 - I cannot perform any of the steps on this page. I've tried this comment, other links, nothing works. Pretty sure I am screwed.

Comment: This worked. I got the message that I had a more up to date version but when I opened IE it was version 10.

Comment: Any idea how to get back IE11 after following this procedure and successfully installing IE10?

Comment: Download it from microsoft : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/internet-explorer-11-for-windows-7-details.aspx . Install it and it should be okay.

Comment: After doing these steps when I go to download Windows 10 from the link provided I instantly get a popup dialog that says, "Internet Explorer Did Not Finish Installing. Internet Explorer 10 is already installed on this system". Before I had Windows 11 and I have never installed or attempted to install Windows 10 before.

Comment: I have prfeormed all above steps on windows 7 and restarted machine. Try to install IE version "IE10-Windows6.1-x64-en-us.exe" and it is showing error message Internet Explorer did not finish installing. Internet Explorer 10 is already installed on this system

Comment: For Windows 8.1, it seems it is impossible to roll back because it comes with IE11 pre-installed. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-iewindows8_1/how-to-go-back-to-internet-explorer-10-on-windows/1194f747-9e6c-43e1-b6b8-d33c6760f00e?auth=1

Comment: There is no update for IE in windows 10, looks like IE comes with windows 10 without update :(

Answer (score 11):

Go to installed updates and just uninstall Internet Explorer 11 Windows update. It works for me.

Comment: uninstalling update is enough and after restart you have your previous IE (10 probably) without installing it

Answer (score 2):

1. Save and close all Internet Explorer windows and then, run Windows Task Manager to end the running processes in background.
2. Go to Control Panel.
3. Click Programs and choose the View installed updates instead.
4. Locate the following Windows Internet Explorer 11 or you can type "Internet Explorer" for a quick search.
5. Choose the Yes option from the following "Uninstall an update".
6. Please wait while Windows Internet Explorer 10 is being restored and reconfigured automatically.
7. Follow the Microsoft Windows wizard to restart your system.

Note: You can do it for as many earlier versions you want, i.e. IE9, IE8 and so on.