# Why does Internet Explorer not work sometimes?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

The full scope of my specific issue is likely too deep to include in a question here. Instead I am looking for clues.

The nature of the problem has to do with `overflow: hidden`. In Internet Explorer 11 it is working sometimes and at other times not. I have an element that is larger than the body and I have set the body element to `overflow: hidden`. Sometimes the page loads and works exactly as expected, but in about 60% of my tests the browser just ignores this property. If I look in the inspector the property and value are present, yet are not having any affect on the rendering of the page.

I have tried using a container element instead of the body, but the same thing happens. opening the inspector panel while scrolled to the top of the page will sometimes fix the issue. Any ideas?

There is a lot going on with this layout which is why there is no fiddle. Everything else works fine in IE. There are no errors in any browser and the layout works perfectly in all other browsers I have tested (Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Opera and IE 11).

Comment: I'd ask "Why does Internet Explorer ever work?" I tend to be more surprised when it does.

Comment: @m59 Not particularly constructive, but hilarious.

Comment: When you've had enough of the bugs: [downgrade](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20043971/how-to-downgrade-from-internet-explorer-11-to-internet-explorer-10)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a `display` properly on that div or element? If you have `display: inline` then try to change to `display:block`.

Comment: I opened up the inspector and made the change and thought "It works!". Then I realized that it only worked because I opened up the panel. Added the rule to the style sheet and sure enough it had no effect. About 60% of the time doesn't work and 40% of the time it works. I think the most strange part is that opening the panel will fix the layout.

Comment: It could be that one of the properties of the divs enclosing it is overriding the one you are setting. In the dev tools, do you see the value you set on strike-through mode? If yes then it is being overwritten by something else.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this worked but I just positioned the body fixed. That seems to work.