# Downgrade to specific IE version (IE 9.0.24)

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, downgrade

I follow the [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20043971/how-to-downgrade-from-internet-explorer-11-to-internet-explorer-10) on how to downgrade IE. But my version now is 9.0.25 and client has 9.0.24. And there are, of course, some errors that are not in 9.0.25... Is it possible to get this exact version?

Answer (score 0):

I **never** tried this solution, but Microsoft proposes free Virtual Machines : https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/windows/

Maybe you can choose specific version of IE9 in it ?

Otherwise, as it is written, these virtual machines **expire after 90 days**. So take a snapshot when you first install the virtual machine which you can roll back to later.