# Selenium waitForElementPresent hangs in IE11

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to test a site with Selenium Grid via recordings from Selenium Builder.  Everything seems to work for Firefox and Chrome on Windows and Mac, but I'm getting error messages when testing in Windows 7 + IE11.

Whenever I try to select or interact with an element I get:

```
Exception: Unable to find element on closed window
```

HTML element I'm waiting for is loaded after page load via jQuery and appears on page as:

```
<input id="email" name="username" type="email" autofocus="autofocus">
```

Selenium Builder Step waits for it to appear before continuing:

```
{
  "locator": {
    "type": "id",
    "value": "email"
  },
  "type": "waitForElementPresent"
},
```

From various posts of people with similar problems I have done the following to try and rectify:

- Made sure the security zones were all the same in IE 11
- Made sure I *wasn't* using any "FLAKY" options anywhere (INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS)

Should I be accessing elements in a different way?  Or is there an IE 11 setting I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Selenium IE guide (https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver) IE 11 has a known problem where security zones can cause issues even when they are all set correctly.

The best option is to downgrade from IE 11 to IE 10 ([How to downgrade from Internet Explorer 11 to Internet Explorer 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20043971/how-to-downgrade-from-internet-explorer-11-to-internet-explorer-10))

This solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

A while ago noticed this strange behavior with IE(Cant remember which version), using Selenium and C#:
When an element is clicked for the second time, the whole thing freezes.
My fix was to keep track of all clicked elements in order to avoid repeated clicks. 
This fixed some of the issues I was having with IE.

Hope it helps.