# Shortcut to copy text from documentation in Matlab 2013b 64-bit on Windows

Tags: matlab, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to copy some text (namely code snippets) from the documentation. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> doesn't work. Is there any shortcut to do it?

I use Matlab 2013b 64-bit on Windows 7 x64 SP1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> [doesn't work](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/104546-why-does-the-help-window-cause-matlab-to-hang-and-why-do-right-click-and-ctrl-c-not-work-in-the-hel) in Matlab 2013b 64-bit's documentation when certain versions of Internet Explorer, in particular IE11 and sometimes IE10, are installed. A workaround is to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> instead.

To get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> working for Matlab 2013b, you can try [downgrading to Internet Explorer 10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20044366/395857) (follow steps 1 to 5).

Comment: Is there a way to get Ctrl + C working for matlab2013b?

Comment: @Basel Downgrading IE might do the trick (haven't tested myself, I have 2014a now)

Comment: Thanks Franck, it worked... You may edit the answer to confirm this case too (simply following the steps here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20043971/how-to-downgrade-from-internet-explorer-11-to-internet-explorer-10).

Comment: @Basel Thanks, done! Did you downgrade to Internet Explorer 10 or Internet Explorer 9?

Comment: Downgraded from IE11 to IE10. Basically, I followed the steps 1-5 of the shared link and then restart.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be an exact answer to your question, but if your intention is to copy code snippets from the documentation in order to later be able to paste them into MATLAB for execution, then instead of using <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> you can use <kbd>F9</kbd>, which executes the selected code directly in MATLAB.