# is it possible to downgrade internet explorer 11 to 10 on windows 8.1 ? How?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, windows-8, windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11

I am working on windows 8.1 but i need to test something on actual IE 10 , not using emulation of IE11 , so how we can downgrade IE11 to IE10 .

Comment: Your question might be answered [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20043971/how-to-downgrade-from-internet-explorer-11-to-internet-explorer-10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 8.1 only has IE 11. To use IE 10 you would have to use Windows 7 or 8 (maybe in a virtual machine - https://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms has some you can use.)

Answer (score 0):

**Windows 8.1 users**

Window 8.1 comes with Internet Explorer 11 pre-installed and cannot be `rolled back`. Your only option is to upgrade to 7.24 (or newer) of the Longbow Converter tool which now supports Internet Explorer 7 emulation mode.

Check this link:

http://blog.longbowsoftware.com/rolling-back-to-ie-10-from-ie-11-in-windows-7-windows-8-and-windows-8-1/